Citation not working on specific template
I'm having a problem with citations in a specific template which is downloadable in the following link:
https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support
I haven't seen this problem before I inserted my text. I uploaded the crude template again to my Overleaf page to check if I made a mistake and deleted something important. In fact, even the examples of referencing and citations of the unchanged template does not work.
Does anybody know how to solve this problem?
        %Version 3 October 2023
% See section 11 of the User Manual for version history
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%                                                                 %%
%% Please do not use \input{...} to include other tex files.       %%
%% Submit your LaTeX manuscript as one .tex document.              %%
%%                                                                 %%
%% All additional figures and files should be attached             %%
%% separately and not embedded in the \TeX\ document itself.       %%
%%                                                                 %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%\documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% referee option is meant for double line spacing

%%=======================================================%%
%% to print line numbers in the margin use lineno option %%
%%=======================================================%%

%%\documentclass[lineno,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style

%%======================================================%%
%% to compile with pdflatex/xelatex use pdflatex option %%
%%======================================================%%

%%\documentclass[pdflatex,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style


%%Note: the following reference styles support Namedate and Numbered referencing. By default the style follows the most common style. To switch between the options you can add or remove Numbered in the optional parenthesis. 
%%The option is available for: sn-basic.bst, sn-vancouver.bst, sn-chicago.bst%  
 
%%\documentclass[sn-nature]{sn-jnl}% Style for submissions to Nature Portfolio journals
%%\documentclass[sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Basic Springer Nature Reference Style/Chemistry Reference Style
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 
%%\documentclass[sn-mathphys-ay]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Author Year Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-aps]{sn-jnl}% American Physical Society (APS) Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-vancouver,Numbered]{sn-jnl}% Vancouver Reference Style
%%\documentclass[sn-apa]{sn-jnl}% APA Reference Style 
%%\documentclass[sn-chicago]{sn-jnl}% Chicago-based Humanities Reference Style

%%%% Standard Packages
%%<additional latex packages if required can be included here>

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{comment}







\newcommand{\revadd}[2][]{#2}
\newcommand{\revrep}[3][]{#3}
\newcommand{\revdel}[2]{}
\newcommand{\revobs}[2][red]{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sgn}{sgn}
\newcommand{\km}[1][\,km]{\ifmmode{\mathrm{#1}}\else{\(\km[#1]\)}\fi}
\newcommand\hcancel[2][black]{\setbox0=\hbox{$#2$}%
\rlap{\raisebox{.45\ht0}{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{\wd0}{1pt}}}}#2} 
%%%%

%%%%%=============================================================================%%%%
%%%%  Remarks: This template is provided to aid authors with the preparation
%%%%  of original research articles intended for submission to journals published 
%%%%  by Springer Nature. The guidance has been prepared in partnership with 
%%%%  production teams to conform to Springer Nature technical requirements. 
%%%%  Editorial and presentation requirements differ among journal portfolios and 
%%%%  research disciplines. You may find sections in this template are irrelevant 
%%%%  to your work and are empowered to omit any such section if allowed by the 
%%%%  journal you intend to submit to. The submission guidelines and policies 
%%%%  of the journal take precedence. A detailed User Manual is available in the 
%%%%  template package for technical guidance.
%%%%%=============================================================================%%%%


%% as per the requirement, new theorem styles can be included as shown below
\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
%%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]% meant for sectionwise numbers
%% optional argument [theorem] produces theorem numbering sequence instead of independent numbers for Proposition
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
%%\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}% to get separate numbers for theorem and proposition etc.

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom
%%\unnumbered% uncomment this for unnumbered level heads

\begin{document}

The citation is \cite{ataghere} does not work.

\end{document}

The following error message appears:
'Package natbib Warning: Citation "ataghere" undefined on inputline XXX.'
I didn't upload anything because the template has many specifications in the .bst file, and I couldn't reproduce here.

Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a minimum working example showing your problem?

The template does not use biblatex, so I have removed that tag to avoid confusion. If you do in fact try to use biblatex with this template, that's probably why things go wrong and the first step to a solution would be not to use biblatex.

@AlainRemillard, sure!, I'll update the post

@moewe I didn't use the biblatex package in this template, but I get it, since this template doesn't use it, I should not use the tag in my question. Thanks for the advice!

When I download the template from the link and try to compile sn-article.tex without any change, I get an error on the BibTeX run, because the .bst files are hidden in the bst folder, but the file name passed to \bibliographystyle uses bare base names. If I move the .bst files one level up from bst to the same directory as sn-article.tex, the file compiles (since the file uses sn-mathphys-num by default, it would be enough to move just that file, but if you use other settings and thus other files, you'll have to move those as well).

@moewe thanks a lot! It worked!

The December 2023 version of the template that can currently be downloaded from https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support has the bibliography style files (.bst files) in a folder called bst. But the class file still assumes that the .bst files reside in the same directory as the main .tex file.
I could compile sn-article.tex without change once I moved all .bst files from the bst folder up one level to the folder that contains sn-article.cls (depending on your settings, the document might use a different .bst file, so I moved all files even though with the unchanged settings you'd only have to move sn-mathphys-num).
