question mark instead of citation
I am using this code but it produces question mark instead of the citation. Also, it says "bib1" is undefined.
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered Reference Style 
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
%%%%

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\title[Article Title]{Article Title}
\author*[1,2]{\fnm{First} \sur{Author}}\email{iauthor@gmail.com}

\author[2,3]{\fnm{Second} \sur{Author}}\email{iiauthor@gmail.com}
\equalcont{These authors contributed equally to this work.}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}

The Introduction section, of referenced text \cite{bib1} expands on the background of the work (some overlap with the Abstract is acceptable).
\bibliography{sn-bibliography}% common bib file

\end{document}

Here is the bib file "sn-bibliography.bib":
@article{bib1,
  author        = "Campbell, S. L. and Gear, C. W.",
  title         = "The index of general nonlinear {D}{A}{E}{S}",
  journal       = "Numer. {M}ath.",
  volume        = "72",
  number        = "2",
  pages         = "173--196",
  year          = "1995"
}


Your code works if I set some bibliography style, e.g. \bibliographystyle{plain} (check with your journal to see which style they want) and compile with pdflatex filename; bibtex filename; pdflatex filename; pdflatex filename

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I add this style right after \begin{document} and it wont work. I compile on overleaf, how can I compile with any of the mentioned options?

@Elika seems to work fine on overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/read/qqnzqtjkpmyr#bc3e56

Off-topic: please replace {D}{A}{E}{S} with {DAEs}. Note that the final letter, "s", should not be uppercased.

Did you run BibTeX? If you downloaded the template from Springer, you may have to move the .bst files. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/717942/35864.

Your example code is far from minimal. Worse, much of the code is irrelevant for the question at hand. Let's consider the following real MWE (minimum working example):
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{bib1,
  author  = "Campbell, Stephen L. and Gear, C. William",
  title   = "The index of general nonlinear {DAEs}",
  journal = "Numerische Mathematik",
  volume  = "72",
  number  = "2",
  pages   = "173--196",
  year    = "1995",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{bib1} 
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv} % or some other suitable bib style
\end{document}

Upon running pdfLaTeX, BibTeX, and pdfLaTeX twice more, one gets the following output:

It looks like the main problem with your code is the absence of a suitable \bibliographystyle directive.

Addendum, prompted by @moewe's very much to-the-point comment: The Dec. 2023 version of the sn-jnl.cls document class file contains the following instructions (among many others, obviously):
\newif\if@Mathphys@numrefstyle\global\@Mathphys@numrefstylefalse% 
%2.Math and Physical Sciences Reference Style -> sn-mathphys-num.bst

....
\DeclareOption{sn-mathphys-num}{\global\@Mathphys@numrefstyletrue}
...
\if@Mathphys@numrefstyle%
  \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}%
  \gdef\NumBib{YES}%
  \bibliographystyle{sn-mathphys-num}%
  \setlength{\bibsep}{1em}%
  \def\bibfont{\reset@font\fontfamily{\rmdefault}\normalsize\selectfont}%
...
\fi

What does this all mean, in plain language? Basically, as you've specified sn-mathphys-num as a document class option, the class file (eventually) tries to (a) load the natbib citation management package and (b) tries to execute
\bibliographystyle{sn-mathphys-num}

It would appear that the file sn-mathphys-num.bst isn't in your working directory, i.e., the directory that contains your main tex file as well as, apparently, the file sn-jnl.cls. Locate the file sn-mathphys-num.bst and copy it to your working directory. That way, you won't have to run an Ersatz command such as \bibliographystyle{abbrv}.

sn-jnl automatically selects a bibliography style, so one should not need a \bibliographystyle. If one downloads the official template from the Springer (at least the Dec 2023 version), the relevant .bst files live in the wrong directory, though, and need to be moved so they can be used: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/717942/35864.

@moewe - Many thanks for your comment and for providing the diagnosis that the OP may have failed to copy a required bst file to their working directory. I've posted an addendum to provide some follow-up instructions.

@moewe this worked!! thanks a lot!
